# Sunspot returning empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using Sunspot for search and my queries aren't returning any results. I am using an API to do the search.

Here is some relevant code:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do 
    text :name, :boost => 5
    text :description
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AppsController < ApiBaseController            
      respond_to :json

      class App < ::App
      end

      def index
        @search = App.search do
          fulltext params[:search]
        end
        @apps = @search.results
        respond_with @apps
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The URL I normally use to access the index method in the AppsController without searching is `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/apps`
When trying to search, I use `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/apps?search=test`
Is my search URL correct or should it be something like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/apps?name=test`
I've tried many different URL formats and they all return an empty result even though there is data in my db. I have also reindexed many times and it shows that 6 items were indexed, which is correct. Any ideas as to what is going on?

EDIT: it works fine when searching from the web app without using the api. It just returns empty when calling from the API url

Comment: y are you using a subclass of `::App` in your controller?

Comment: It's there in case I want to add some data to the API requests that are different than the actual model

Comment: I should just comment it out for now

Comment: I actually just removed that ::App code in my controller and it worked! If you want to make that into an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would try to remove the `::App` subclassing in your controller. my guess is it messes up sunspots or activerecords inference mechanisms regarding the table <-> class naming conventions.